# Is there a way to execute quires on the backend with firebase?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to have a collection with all the users and I want to store their current location.

I will have a function that is calculating the distance from the current user location to the location of each user that is in the collection and I want to receive only the users that are X kilometers away from the current users.

I can get all the users and filter them on the front-end but wont that be a lot of document reads if there are a lot of users ?

Is there a way to pass the current user location to firebase and do the filtering on the server side ? Or the only way is to get all the users and filter them on the front-end ?

Comment: You can filter on fronend side too! If user's location is `(l,m)`, filter location whose latitude is greater than `l-X` and less than `l+X`. Similar for longitiude. You will find the users within the square surrounding. This is not accurate because some locations might be up to 1.414*X, so you *would also* have to implement frontend filtering. Yet, this would filter the number of results significantly.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid doing large amounts of work in your client app, you can use [Cloud Functions for Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions) to create a backend API endpoint and push that work to a hosted backend.  A full discussion of a possible implementation is too long for a Stack Overflow answer, but you will want to read that documentation to get started building a backend.  One easy approach is to write a [callable function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable) that you can invoke directly from the client.  The function can then use the [Firebase Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup) to query the database, perform some computations, and return the results to the app.